# Is Is Possible To Parse HTML Containing Escape Characters In React

Tags: html, reactjs

Is there any way to parse the below example in React?

As in remove the escape characters from the closing html tags so that it can be rendered using setInnnerHtml?

```
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog, or something like that.<\/p>\n<p>Advantages:<\/p>\n
```

This is what is being returned from an API, what can I do?

Thanks

Comment: Explain "parse". Are you wanting to just render it? or what is the goal? If just rendering, check out the docs for [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Comment: Sorry, yes. I want to be able to render it. I have updated my question.

Comment: Just run it though the `unescape` function.

Comment: Hah, I didn't know there was one. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to display that HTML in your react page you can do it like this

```
 <p
     dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: yourHTMLBlock }}
 ></p>
```

Comment: That doesn't currently work due to the escape characters in the closing tags

Comment: I copied your exact output and it worked for me, do you get any errors?

Comment: See this link for an example https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-hugle-kxgt4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: It displays without formatting. Does yours render with proper formatting?

Comment: It seems to have the formatting for me, see the codesandbox above.

Comment: Thanks for the example, I have used it test a couple of items returned from the api and they all work fine. That's annoying, lol

Comment: No, I'm not sure why. I'm using Next, maybe they change the behaviour somehow, I'll have a look through the docs. Thanks for the example though, that was really helpful. You've inspired me to start using codesandbox for testing this kind of thing in future.